# Restart Oozie on EMR cluster after making changes to oozie-site.xml

Tags: oozie, emr

I am trying to restart Oozie server after making changes to the oozie-site.xml. But, so far, I am not successful. I am using EMR 4.3 version of the cluster.

Comment: You should be able to do it from `OOZIE_HOME/bin/oozied.sh start|stop`.

Comment: @YoungHobbit I did it from /usr/lib/oozie/bin/oozied.sh start|stop .